# Hashmap with ArrayList data type (Kotlin)?

Tags: android, kotlin

This is the variables and addControl fun I used.

```
var arrayTQ = ArrayList<TongQuan>()
var arrayBG = ArrayList<BangGia>()
var epdbLV: ExpandableListView? = null
var listHeader: List<String> = listOf()
var listChild = HashMap<String, ArrayList<Any>>()

var arrayListData = ArrayList<String>()
private fun addControl() {
    epdbLV = findViewById(R.id.epdbList)
    listHeader = ArrayList()
    listChild = HashMap<String, ArrayList<Any>>()
    listHeader = listOf("Tổng Quan Thị Quan Thị Trường, Bảng Giá, Lịch Sự Kiện, Tin Tức, Chỉ Số Thế Giới")
    arrayListData = ArrayList()
    arrayTQ = ArrayList()
    arrayBG = ArrayList()
}
```

And I put the listChild.put into override fun in inner class GetData extend AsyncTask. The error at arrayTQ is about the type of data TongQuan not match with Any. In Java, It is no need to add typedata after ArrayList in HashMap. Help me fix it, I had searched and tried. Thanks Guys.

```
override fun onPostExecute(result: ArrayList<String>) {
        super.onPostExecute(result)
        getDataTQ()
        getDataBG()
        listChild.clear()
        listChild.put(listHeader.get(1), arrayTQ)
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ArrayList<TongQuan>` is not a child of `ArrayList<Any>`.

So instead of this: `listChild = HashMap<String, ArrayList<Any>>()`

you should have: `listChild = HashMap<String, ArrayList<TongQuan>>()`

---

However, this will let you add only `ArrayList<TongQuan>`. If you want the ability to add `ArrayList<TongQuan>` or `ArrayList<BangGia>`, then you need to do the below:

`listChild = HashMap<String, ArrayList<out Any>>()`

For a detailed documentation on Variance, refer here: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html

Answer (score 0):

`Any` is different with `Object` in Java. Unlike in java where every class is child of Object, in kotlin not every class is child of `Any`.

Instead of using ArrayList, you should use kotlin List.
it should work like this:

```
ar arrayTQ = mutableListOf<TongQuan>()
var arrayBG = mutableListOf<BangGia>()
var epdbLV: ExpandableListView? = null
var listHeader: List<String> = listOf()
var listChild = HashMap<String, List<Any>>()

var arrayListData = mutableListOf<String>()
private fun addControl() {
    epdbLV = findViewById(R.id.epdbList)
    listHeader = ArrayList()
    listChild = HashMap<String, List<Any>>()
    listHeader = listOf("Tổng Quan Thị Quan Thị Trường, Bảng Giá, Lịch Sự Kiện, Tin Tức, Chỉ Số Thế Giới")
    arrayListData.clear()
    arrayTQ.clear()
    arrayBG.clear()
}
```

it should be safe to call

```
override fun onPostExecute(result: ArrayList<String>) {
        super.onPostExecute(result)
        getDataTQ()
        getDataBG()
        listChild.clear()
        listChild.put(listHeader.get(1), arrayTQ)
    }
```

as @Henry suggest, you should read kotlin *Variance* https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html

Comment: Thank you guys! Both worked correctly. I'm reading, learning that.